# Get the value of an input box outside a form

Tags: php, forms, post, input

I am trying to figure out a way to get the value of an input box that is not in a form and put it in the URL of a form under it. Here is what I am talking about:

```
        <div id="wrapper">
                <h1>[ <input type="text" name="to" id="to" placeholder="To"> ]</h1>
                <div id="menu">
                    <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo htmlentities($user); ?></b></p>
                    <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Logout</a </p>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                </div>

            <div id="chatbox"></div>
                <form name="message" action="../new_private.php?n=<?php echo $_POST['to']; ?>" method="post">
                    <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63">
                    <input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send">
                    <input name="from" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user; ?>">
                </form>
        </div>
```

When I try it this way, I get an undefined error saying `$_POST['to'] is not a valid index.`

I would like to get the value of the input box "to" and put into the URL for the form under it. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Comment: make sure you have the `input` you want to post, inside the form element

Comment: Since you would be taking client-side information to update an already rendered page, you would need to use a client-side library like JavaScript

Comment: @Luke Javascript is not a library. It is a programming language.

Comment: @Phil There are many beginners may read this and it may leads to misconception. Indeed, the term `pedantic` should be used carefully regarding concepts and basic principles. However, it is just a notice after to clear any, probable, conception.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Shame I can't edit it.

Comment: @Phil Well, could you tell me any other programming language  than javascript that could deals with the DOM library in the browser and you and me as clients of the application able to receive its output in the OP web application? It may be Macromedia ActionScript after installing flash plugin or VBScript in old MSIE!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML5, you can include `<input>` elements outside the `<form>` by using the [`form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form) with the value of the form's `id`.

For example...

```
<h1>[ <input type="text" name="n" id="to" placeholder="To" form="message"> ]</h1>

<!-- snip -->

<form id="message" action="../new_private.php" method="post">
```

---

The only difference here would be that the `n` field will be in `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

---

If you really need the value in the URL, you'll need some JavaScript. Something like this

```
<h1>[ <input type="text" name="to" id="to" placeholder="To"> ]</h1>

<!-- snip -->

<form name="message" action="../new_private.php" method="post">
  <!-- form contents, etc -->
</form>
<script>
(function() { // IIFE so as not to pollute the global scope
  const form = document.forms.message
  const action = form.action // original action
  document.getElementById('to').addEventListener('input', function() {
    form.action = action + '?n=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value)
  }, false)
})()
</script>
```

Comment: From [this resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Global_%3Cinput%3E_attributes) The `form` attribute should be the `id` attribute of the form.

Comment: @SaidbakR isn't that what I said and have in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I realized it after a while, but generally and more simple in the case of editing the form, it will be better to raise up the form tag few lines above, will not it?

Comment: @SaidbakR I don't think it matters at all. The choice of how to structure the document in this case is purely subjective.

Comment: Form attribute on a input field does not work on IE according to [this source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form.asp) (scroll to bottom for browser support).

Comment: @Allart nobody should be supporting any version of IE these days.

Comment: Depends what target audience you are writing it for I guess... Its just a comment for users who might have to work with IE.